# Slide in divs with JS animate in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have built boxes which come in like notifications.
I now want to slide them in with a soft movement from left, not just the fade.

I now, that I have to do this with .animate and not with .fadeIn.

My animate code I would try with would be (don't know, if this would work):

```
animate(
    document.getElementByClassName('notification'),
    "margin-left","px",50,0,200;
    "opacity",0,1,200;
);
```

But! I have no idea, how to integrate this into the function :(

Here is my JS:

```
var myVar;

function showDiv() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval() {
  setTimeout(showDiv, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  createRandomInterval();
});
```

Here is my complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brapbg1h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i would use animate to get your expected result, basically you replace the .hide() with the animate function

```
function showDiv() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    marginLeft: '-200px'
  }, 'slow', 'linear');
  createRandomInterval();
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brapbg1h/4/)

Comment: Nice thank you! For everybody, this is my final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/brapbg1h/6/